# Can Docusign CRCL use a filter?

Tags: docusignapi

When using the Docusign CRCL parameter to pull Contacts from a related list, is it possible to select only certain Contacts to be signers? For example, I have a related list under the Contract object that contains 4 Contact names.  Is it possible to select only 2 of those Contacts to be Signer 1 and Signer 2 based on custom fields stored on the records?

Answer (score 2):

Normally, in a custom button you can use the CRL line to add Contact Roles to the Signer role and then the CCRM Role...like so:

```
    DST='';
    CRL='LoadDefaultContact~0';
    CCRM='Decision Maker~Signer 1;Executive Sponsor~Signer 2;OppOwner!Signer 3;
```

So basically, in your contact roles related list, the contact that is labeled the 'Decision Maker' will automatically be made Signer 1 and the 'Executive Sponsor' is Signer 2. So all you have to do is make sure that the two of the four roles you want to select as signers and make them one of these two roles.

Hope this helps